# Как выделить из текста ключевые слова по определенной тематике?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, nlp

Всем добрый день! Я новичок в ML, поэтому буду благодарна любой помощи.

Передо мной стоит следующая задача: перед обучением модели, требуется обработать данные - вычленить из текста (описание вакансии) ключевые слова, по которым можно будет понять, что это за профессия.

Вот как выглядят мои данные для обучения:
[image: По заданию нужно предсказать значения для колонки "target_prof"]

Пример:

- **Соответствующая профессия:** повар
- **Название вакансии:**  Повар-универсал
- **Описание вакансии после предобработки (см. ниже):** обязанность приготовление пф блюдо холодного цех работа с выпечка мелко штучка требование опыт работа умение работать ттк наличие мед книжка условие заработный плата руб час ежемесячный премии график работа до питание униформа мед осмотр счёт компания
- **Пример массива слов, который я хочу получить (для дальнейшего обучения модели):** ['блюдо', 'выпечка']

Но проблема заключается в том, что в датасете для обучения содержится свыше 50.000 текстов с описаниями вакансий. И пока что я не вижу никакого другого решения, кроме как создать массив с незначащими словами, по которому в дальнейшем будет проходить поиск и удаление слов, что содержатся в тексте. Также я не уверена, что такой подход можно считать верным, так как отбор слов вручную подразумевает субъективность, что плохо, наверное.

```
"""Пример реализации моей идеи"""

# массив незначащих слов, которые не помогут определить профессию по описанию вакансии
word_filter = ['работа', 'обязанность', 'умение', 'наличие'] # и т.д.
# массив всех слов из описания вакансии
description = ['обязанность', 'приготовление', 'блюдо', 'цех', 'работа', 'выпечка'] # и т.д.
for word in description:
    if word in word_filter:
        description.remove(word)
```

До этого, в качестве обработки сырого текста мной было предпринято следующее:

- удалены все html-теги, что остались после парсинга
- удалены все знаки препинания, лишние символы, emoji
- Удалены все цифры (они не играют роли для определения профессии по описанию вакансии)
- Удалены такие части речи как: наречия, сравнительные формы слов, причастия, деепричастия, местоимения, предлоги и пр.
- Все слова поставлены в начальную форму

Если у вас есть какие-либо идеи или замечания по поводу данной задачи, то пишите, с радостью всё поясню:) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Погодите, но ведь речь о `машинном обучении`, верно? И данные у вас, похоже, размечены (ну, или хотя бы их часть). Так почему бы не применить машинное обучение для вашей задачи? Для начала возьмите какой-нибудь простой `CountVectorizer`, преобразуйте слова в векторное представление, обучите какую-то модель, у которой можно посмотреть важность фич (для LR это абсолютная величина коэффициентов, у большинства других моделей тоже есть механизмы подсчёта важности фич). Ну и у каких слов больше важность - те и важны для определения профессии. А у каких важность по мнению модели слабая - попробуйте убирать эти слова и посмотрите, что будет с качеством предсказаний модели. Если слова действительно не значащие, то качество не ухудшится, а то и улучшится. Ну, там есть ещё детали, но в общих чертах можно подойти к проблеме так.

Я пробовал подобный подход применять к текстам судебных решений, чтобы определить их тип, он вполне работает. Возможно только придётся использовать не одиночные слова, а `n-граммы` из слов (обычно достаточно одиночных слов, плюс сочетаний из 2-х слов), а то и эмбеддинги `word2vec` для улучшения качества моделей, но это вполне рабочий подход.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Правда, видимо, я не очень понятно выразилась: мои данные размечены под задачу - предсказание профессии: то есть каждому описанию и названию вакансии соответствует определенная профессия. Поэтому размеченных данных для вычленения ключевых слов у меня нет.. Возможно, есть смысл вручную составить для данной подзадачи датасет, но я не имею представления насколько большим он должен быть..

Comment: Либо я вас не понимаю, либо вы меня. "вычленить из текста (описание вакансии) ключевые слова, по которым можно будет понять, что это за профессия." Ну то есть конечная цель вычленения слов - понять профессию? Под профессию данные размечены? Фичи - слова, целевая переменная - профессия. Берёте модели, у которых можно легко увидеть важность фич. Для начала хоть логистическую регрессию. А дальше смотрите её коэффициенты. Например, наибольшие коэффициенты для каждого класса. Смотрите, каким словам они соответствуют. Всё. Ну там может ещё нормализовать нужно будет фичи, ещё что-то.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html делаете ей fit и смотрите coef_. Возможно нужно будет более сложные модели типа RandomForestClassifier использовать и там смотреть feature_importances_

Comment: А, всё, теперь поняла вас! Спасибо за доступное объяснение!)

Comment: Дальше у вас наверняка ещё вопросы возникнут и это нормально, но вы главное начните работать в этом направлении, постепенно разберётесь. Что непонятно будет - спрашивайте тут на SO, отвечу я или ещё кто. )

Comment: Вообще `feature importances` - отдельная большая интересная тема и подходов к ней много. Начнёте разбираться хотя бы на начальном уровне - потом легче будет.